# Boot strap modal not sizing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Ive got a modal in my rails application, In my last project it worked fine, but in this new one it doesnt resize properly. In full screen it clamps to the right side of the window and gets reall small, If I make the window small enough for it to resize it looks right. If i make it bigger again, its still the wrong size.

Wrong : https://i.stack.imgur.com/t93YQ.jpg

Right : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ96r.jpg

Comment: Well if could paste your code, then I might be able to figure out the cause for distortion.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4k367rgM
This is the modal partial 



`<a href="#" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-question-modal">Help</a>`




This is the line for the button. 

The partial is being rendered in the index view of the class.

Comment: Do you have any `css` defined for this modal ?

Comment: None outside of the standard bootstrap 3.3.5 bootstrap.min.css

Comment: The code you have given, is working fine at my end. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0905gapdac

Comment: Just make sure, you do not have any unclosed `<div>` in your file. That could be the cause of error. Also if possible, provide complete file, so that I can debug.

Comment: The rest of the file that partial gets rendered in is here : http://pastebin.com/5pHN682X

Comment: You have extra `<table>` in your code at line 4.

Comment: I noticed that and removed it, doesnt seem to change the modal issue though

Comment: I am sorry, then I couldn't be of any help. I can't solve it if I can't produce it. Because in code, I don't find anything that could cause error.

Comment: Here is the full paste of the output html, as rendered in my view source of the browser. http://pastebin.com/tmG7dPZW

If that cant reproduce it It must be my browser